# Why did Eagleton omit to explain "literary theory" in "Literary Theory: An Introduction"?

Tags: theory, literary-theory-an-introduction, terry-eagleton

In Terry Eagleton’s preface to the first (1983) edition of *Literary Theory: An Introduction* he writes:

> This book sets out to provide a reasonably comprehensive account of modern literary theory for those with little or no previous knowledge of the topic.

In light of this stated purpose, a curious aspect of the book is that Eagleton never explains what “literary theory” is. The introduction begins:

> If there is such a thing as literary theory, then it would seem obvious that there is something called literature which it is the theory of. We can begin, then, by raising the question: what is literature?

A reader might imagine that Eagleton is merely postponing the explanation of “literary theory” until after he has explained “literature”, but this does not happen: chapter 1 is a narrative of the rise of the academic study of English literature, and chapters 2 to 5 consider various twentieth-century academic trends (phenomenology; structuralism; post-structuralism; psychoanalysis). Finally, in the conclusion, Eagleton writes:

> In the course of this book we have considered a number of problems of literary theory. But the most important question of all has as yet gone unanswered.

A reader might think that by this point “the most important question of all” is, “what is literary theory?” But no! The question is actually:

> What is the *point* of literary theory?

This lacuna—failing to explain or define the very subject of the book—is so glaring that it demands some account. Did Eagleton forget? Did he assume that all readers (even the intended reader from the preface with “no previous knowledge of the topic”) would already know what it is? Was the omission deliberate? If deliberate, what was Eagleton’s reason for omitting it? Did Eagleton think that it would be best for his readers to form the concept of “literary theory” by generalization from the examples he gives? Was there an *aporia* or difficulty in committing to a particular meaning of the term? Was it a case of “the Tao that can be named is not the true Tao” or “if you have to ask, you ain’t never gonna know”?

That Eagleton eventually recognized there was a problem is, I think, evident from the new preface he wrote for the 2008 edition, where he does give a definition ([page viii](https://archive.org/details/terryeagletonliterarytheoryanintroductionzlib.org/page/n7/mode/2up)).

Comment: I can't view the page you link from the 2008 edition. For the sake of the curious, could you edit to quote how he does eventually define literary theory? Maybe knowing his definition would help to understand why he didn't include it originally.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have substituted a different link. I deliberately didn't quote it because there is a risk of assuming that Eagleton had the 2008 definition in mind all along, which might not be the case.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. Yes, if you have to ask, you probably won't get the answer, meaning if you have to ask it is doubtful you will ever be satisfied with any answer you are given. Since the content of the book describes examples instantiating literary theory in semi-chronological order, isn't that material that Eagleton serves the reader for generalization and inductive inference? He also makes it sufficiently clear literary theory can be assumed to be the theory of something call "literature". I don't see why the focal point should be literary theory not literature.